# How to update a rendered javascrtipt from another script tag?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have the following code, that uses `FullCalendar` and renders a calendar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          events: [
             {
                title: "Test",
                startTime: "12:00:00",
                endTime: "13:00:00",
                startRecur: "2022-03-02",
                endRecur: "2022-03-02",
             },
          ],
        });
        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <script>
        const events = [
             {
                title: "Test 2",
                startTime: "10:00:00",
                endTime: "11:00:00",
                startRecur: "2022-03-03",
                endRecur: "2022-03-03",
             },
          ];
        document.getElementById('calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvents', events);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

With the second script tag I try to update the events. This will be triggered later in a separate function.
The script is not updating the events. I somehow understand, that the HTMLElement does not have a property `fullCalendar`, but I don't understand, what I need to do else. What do I need to do to update the events using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Move both scripts into DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: The reason why I want to do is, is because I want to modify the already loaded events late during runtime of the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few issues with your attempt:

1. `document.getElementById('calendar')` is the wrong thing to target when trying to update the calendar. That would get the HTML DOM element which contains the HTML used to render the calendar. But that isn't the same as the fullCalendar JavaScript object which represents the calendar in code and contains all of its method calls, properties etc. The calendar's model object and it's HTML representation are two separate things.
2. `.fullCalendar(...` isn't correct either. That's legacy syntax from fullCalendar v3 and below, when it was implemented as jQuery plugin. (I guess maybe you found an old example online and didn't check against current documentation.)
3. In v5 there's no direct equivalent of the `'updateEvents'` method found in v3 of fullCalendar anyway. Since you're using a static array of events rather than a dynamic event source, to "update" them you need to either [get all the events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) or [get the specific event you're interested in](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById), and on each event which you want to alter you then must [set the necessary properties](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp) as per your requirements. Or you could [remove](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove) the event and [add a brand new one](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent). But instead of all that it would probably be a lot easier to use an [event source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source) instead, which you can then add/remove/refresh dynamically (and thus be able to alter all of its events at once).
4. The `calendar` variable which, in your code, contains the fullCalendar object produced by executing `new FullCalendar.Calendar`, and which you need to target for your purpose, is only [in scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) within the `DOMContentLoaded` callback where it was declared. The code in the second `<script>` block you've shown appears to run immediately when the page loads, so currently this would happen *before* the calendar has even been created. It's unclear when you actually want this to run (since immediately replacing all the events you initialised the calendar with seems a bit pointless), so I'll leave that up to you to fill in the gap. But you can make the `calendar` object in global scope by simply declaring `var calendar;` *before* the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` line, and then writing `calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {` (i.e. without the `var` within it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet. Regarding 4.: When I move the calendar outside the function, I get `Can't find variable: FullCalendar`. Even if I move the `<script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>` at the end of the body.

Comment: My bad. I basically removed the entire event listener. Now I declared the `var calendar;` and removed the `var` from inside and I get `[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'calendar.render')`

Comment: @PeterPan Hmm, obviously I can't see precisely how you've written it in yours, but this is what I was intending, and it works: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYebprX

Comment: Adding `console.log(calendar);` to the end of your script shows `undefined`. Thus, it is still not globally available?

Comment: Adding `calendar.setOption('events', [{title: "Test2", start: "2022-03-03"}]); calendar.refetchEvents();` at the end gives me `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'calendar.setOption')`

Comment: @PeterPan if you add it fully to the end, it will still run the console.log command _before_ the calendar has been initialised, because the `DomContentLoaded` callback doesn't run until the whole page is loaded, whereas the script outside that will run as soon as the browser receives that bit of code (which if the code is near the top of the page, will be before most other things are loaded). So that's why you get that. Once the calendar has actually been initialised, the value will be available globally from then on. You need to wait till the calendar has loaded before you try to use it!